# Object column in DataGridPro

Tags: mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

Is there a way to access a column object in DataGridPro and include it in the quick search? The object structure is as below:

```
[{
  Id: "xxx",
  obj: [{ objId: "1", somethingInside: "" }, { objId: "2", somethingInside: "" }]
}]
```

I've tried declaring the column for the obj as below but no luck.

```
{
 align: "left",
 headerAlign: "left",
 field: "obj.objId",
 headerName: "Object",
 description: "Object",
 type: "string",
 flex: 1,
 width: UNDEFINED,
 minWidth: 0,
 filterable:  TRUE,
 sortable:   false,
}
```